# Open PopUp When Browser is close/tab's closes or Navigate to other page

Tags: asp.net

I have to open a popup to get user input and save to the database using either of jquery/javascript or server side event, when user close the browser/close the tab or Navigate to other pages on the site. Please guide me on this. I have tried using

`window.onbeforeunload = function evens(evt) {}`

But, Not working.

Comment: kindly put more code to understand what you have done ...

Comment: what i have done is
window.onbeforeunload = function evens(evt) {
$("#ShowPopUp").show();
});
<div id="ShowPopUp">
   <TextBox>
   <Button>
</div>
My Requirement is when user click on Close Tab/Browser or Navigate to different page 
the above popup should appear and when User enter some value in textbox and click on submit button than it should update the Database and the original event which user fire i.e Click on Close Tab/Browser or navigate to different page should execute. Did you get my query?